# How to exclude elements with certain class names when triggering JS function calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

One approach to generically trigger a JS function call from one place could be:

```
$("textarea").blur(function);
```

How would one alter this statement to exclude textarea elements that contained say class="donotprocess", ie apply the "onblur" event to all textarea elements apart from those that have class="donotprocess"?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, add the tag to your question.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try with [`:not()` Selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$("textarea:not(.donotprocess)").blur(function);
```